# Nodes in a intersection of a general smooth hypersurface and a smooth hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It is known that for a general hypersurface of degree $\ge 5$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$, any hyperplane section can have at most $3$ nodes.

(1). Let $H_1$ be a sufficiently general smooth hypersurface of degree $m\ge 5$ and  $H_2$ be a smooth hypersurface of degree $n \ge 5$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$.  Let $Y$ be the complete intersection $H_1 \cap H_2$. How many nodes $Y$ can have ?

(2). In (1) if $H_1$ is sufficiently general but $H_2$ is arbitrary, then how many nodes $Y$ can have ?

Comment: By the same technique as in my previous answer, for $n\geq m$, you can find a smooth hypersurface $H_2$ such that the intersection with $H_1$ is a connected curve with $n$ irreducible components and $\min(t,n)+2n + mn(n-1)/2$ nodes, where $t$ is the number of tritangent planes (I do not remember the formula for $t$ off the top of my head, but it is straightforward to compute).